# Try to upload an image, but req.file is undefined from my multer

Tags: node.js, multer

My code is extremely simple and almost follow the tutorial on Multer git, but my req.file is still undefined:

Here's my html to upload the image:

```html
<form action="/product/upload_image" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"> 

  <input id="product_image" type="file" name="product_image" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg"/>      

   <input type="submit" value="Upload image"/>
</form>
```

My routes:

```
var multer = require("multer")
var upload = multer({ dest: "uploads/" })

router.post("/product/upload_image", upload.single("product_image"), function(req, res) {
 console.log(req.file)
}
```

And it returns undefined

Comment: what you are using as frontent?

Comment: Is your problem resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const indexRouter = require('./index.js')
app.use('/', indexRouter)
const PORT = 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('it started on 5000'))
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router()
var multer = require("multer")
var upload = multer({ dest: "uploads/" })

router.get('/', (req, res) =>
res.sendFile('upload.html', {root: __dirname })
)

router.post("/product/upload_image", upload.single("product_image"), (req, res)=>
 console.log(req.file)
) 
module.exports = router
```

upload.html

```
<form action="/product/upload_image" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"> 

    <input id="product_image" type="file" name="product_image" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg"/>      

     <input type="submit" value="Upload image"/>
  </form>
```

I tried your code. It's working fine. Please try this.

Comment: Yes, It's working with ejs as well. You want me to share code?